# Batch set date time attribute according to the names of the files in a folder

Tags: batch-file

Thanks for reading and for possible answer.

I've got a folder with files named yyyymmddhhMMss.m2ts, say 20120330193059.m2ts. Actually they are outputs from a Sony camcorder with extra files with metadata missing.

To get them properly organized I need to set "date created" and "date modified" file attributes according to their filenames, as all necessary data are already present there.

I'm totally far from any kind of programming or coding but I thought I could compile the .cmd myself using examples I could find. But now I must admit I've failed with that.

I understand that I must get a filename into variable, split this variable into 6 parts and then apply them as a file attribute for every file in the folder. But I can't understand how.

There are plenty of examples of how to rename a file according to their timestamp but not vice versa.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't just renaming them 2012-03-30_19-30-59 be enough? That would be much easily doable.

Comment: Unfortunately, not. When you have thousands of small video phragments and need to make a bluray or dvd with calendar based menu created automatically (it is the key word as I would create such a menu by hands untill my sad death with such numbers of files) you need to obey the rules of the mastering software. Sony's PMB can recreate the metadata but only according to the date created and date modified attributes. And nothing else.

Comment: I don't think there are any commands available from the Windows command line that can change that. I've looked through the entire list now, but I haven't seen anything. In this case, I don't think there is an easy way to do it with a batch file or do it at all. I will look for more, but I don't think it's doable in this way.

Comment: Maybe you should try looking for special software that could do this. I don't think you can access those attribute fields with command line commands.

Comment: Why not? For getting the YEAR I must trim the last 10 characters from the file name. For getting the MONTH I must trim the first 4 and the last 8 characters and so on. I don't think it would be difficult for any person with the basic knowledge of the windows shell scripting language. Hope they would read this willing to help.

Comment: Maybe with the help of some 3rd party software, such as from http://www.abf-dev.com for example that can be included into the batch script.

Comment: I don't mean taking the day, month, year,etc. from the file name. I meant about changing the file's `Date created` and `Date modified` attributes. These should be stored in the file's header.Maybe trying to read the file, line by line looking for these identifiers, maybe then you could use the information in the file name and insert it into the file itself, at the right places so when you right click your photo and go to it's properties and file summary you will see that the `Date created` and `Date modified` are updated. I'd try this if you would upload your file somewhere and share a link.

Comment: Here is a snip from the ABF's Freeware Tools (http://www.abf-dev.com/download.shtml - in the very bottom of the page)

Comment: Impossible to add text with paragraphs, sorry... So, the ABF's Filedate from their Freeware Tools can do the batch job with the only problem of adding "/" delimiters into date and "-" into time variables. It is not a problem to upload the files but I don't want to alter them any way other than just change their timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the Batch file below. Use a set of test files first.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set origDate=%date%
set origTime=%time%
for %%f in (*.*) do (
   set fName=%%~Nf
   set fDate=!fName:~4,2!/!fName:~6,2!/!fName:~0,4!
   set fTime=!fName:~8,2!:!fName:~10,2!:!fName:~12,2!
   REM Next line update just "Date Modified" in a fast way:
   REM echo !fDate!| date & echo !fTime!| time & copy "%%f" +,,
   REM Next 4 lines update both "Modified" and "Created" dates, but it is slower:
   echo !fDate!| date & echo !fTime!| time & copy "%%f" "%%~Nf.tmp"
   echo !fTime!| time & copy "%%~Nf.tmp" +,,
   del "%%f"
   ren "%%~Nf.tmp" "%%f"
)
echo %origDate%| date
echo %origTime%| time
```

This Batch file requires that you have credentials enough to change the system clock. It assume that `echo %date%` display the date in MM/DD/YYYY format; if not, a slightly modification is needed. If the number of files to process is large, the system clock may be put back a few seconds; perhaps you need to manually reset the system clock when the Batch file ends.

Please, report the results.

**EDIT**: I included the two parts (Modified and Created dates) in the same listing above.

Comment: My previous comment was a bit wrong so please ignore it if you have already received e-mail notification. Your batch perfectly changes date modified field in almost no time, no matter of the size of the files being changed. So THANK YOU very much, you have saved a lot of time and composure for me. I have to correct the time after the batch finished but Windows does it automatically, so it is not a problem at all. The second part of the batch changes last accessed attribute, not date created.

Comment: @Garfield: I tested this method and works correctly (with one file). Please, copy the program above again, that I had modified to update both dates, and test it. It MUST correctly update both dates; if not, then the cause is an error, because the process is into a FOR loop, that may be solved.

Comment: It again changess Modified and Accessed but leaves Created intact. Anyway it seems that PMB uses only the Modified attribute to determine the recording date, so don't worry about Created. You have helped me a lot already. Actually you did everything I needed. I understood almost nothing in the script but it works and it is ok. Thanks again, you've really helped a lot.